# Execute asynchronous javascript code every X seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, repeat, function-calls

How to execute asynchronous js code (written in node.js) every X seconds and ensure that the new execute/call won't be started before the callback (success, error) from asynchronous function is executed. Code example:

```
asyncFunc(function(successData){
  // do something with successData
}, function(errorData){
  // do something with errorData
});
```

setInterval comes to my mind firstly, but I think it won't ensure what I want, if the callback doesn't execute inside interval, it will go to the queue.

**EDIT: To simplify case, repeat async function call 1 second after its callback finishes.**

Comment: Do you want to execute your code every X seconds, or X seconds after the previous call have finished ?

Comment: and if the previous callback is still running, how long do you want to wait before starting the next run?   Do it immediately, or wait until n*X seconds after the previous call, or X seconds?

Comment: Ok, I will change my question to simplify case. Repeat function call 1 second after callback finishes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setTimeout` like this:

```
(function loop() {
    asyncFunc(function(successData){
        setTimeout(loop, X);
    }, function(errorData){
        // If you still want to continue:
        setTimeout(loop, X);
    });
})(); // execute immediately
```

This will start the delay when the async call triggers the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Consider abstracting the problem with a re-usable method that'll allow you to specify the function to call, the interval at which it's called, and the callbacks to invoke:

```
function repeatAsync(func, interval, success, error) {
    (function loop() {
        func(
            () => {
                success();
                setTimeout(loop, interval);
            },
            () => {
                error();
                setTimeout(loop, interval);
            }
        );
    })();   // invoke immediately
}
```

If you want the chain of calls to be broken on error, replace the second argument to `func` with just `error`, i.e. `func( () => { ... }, error)`